# Join two MYSQL columns in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two MYSQL tables: "product" and "url_alias".

```
+------------+--------+
|        product      |
+------------+--------+
| product_id | status |
+------------+--------+
|          1 |      1 |
|          2 |      0 |
|          3 |      1 |
+------------+--------+

+------------+------------+
|        url_alias        |
+--------------+----------+
|    query     | keyword  |
+--------------+----------+
| product_id=1 | keyword1 |
| product_id=2 | keyword2 |
| product_id=3 | keyword3 |
+--------------+----------+
```

I am writing PHP code to extract the keyword column from **url_alias** table but only for the product_id that has corresponding status = 1 in the **product** table. I figured this will involve joining the two columns and using a filter at the same time.

```php
$sql  = "
SELECT p.product_id
     , ua.keyword 
  FROM `".$this->tables["product"]."` p 
 WHERE p.status = 1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN `".$this->tables["url_alias"]."` ua 
    ON ua.query = CONCAT('product_id=',p.product_id) ";
```

So far I am getting:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: This smells bad. if `query` column always = `product_id={id}` then make it an int and remove the `product_id=` part. If the column contains more varied data `{string}{id}` then split into two columns `querystring` and `queryid`

Comment: It's surprising that that's all that the error message says. You must be using a very special version of mysql.

Comment: Friendly tip: When facing SQL syntax errors, hammer out the queries in the DB's console first if you have access to it (Command line, phpmyadmin, etc). When you get the desired result, start converting it into a php friendly string.

Comment: @harris I agree, that is good practice but I already tried that, couldn't get it to work there either.

Comment: @Strawberry the rest of the error message wasn't adding anything useful to this post, it was just my syntax echoed, so I left it out.

Comment: I seriously doubt that that's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply try as

```
$sql  = "SELECT p.product_id,ua.keyword FROM `".$this->tables["product"]."` p ";
$sql .= "LEFT JOIN `".$this->tables["url_alias"]."` ua ON ua.query=CONCAT('product_id=',p.product_id) ";
$sql .= " WHERE p.status=1";
```

As you didn't define the error but looking at your query it's because of you were applying where condition before join it should be after join

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sql  = "SELECT p.product_id,ua.keyword FROM ".$this->tables["product"]." as p WHERE p.status=1 ";
$sql .= "LEFT JOIN ".$this->tables["url_alias"]." as ua ON ua.query = CONCAT('product_id=',p.product_id) ";
```

You have missed out the 'as'.

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotation of tablename after From.
Try this query

```
   $sql  = "SELECT p.product_id,ua.keyword FROM ".$this->tables["product"]." p WHERE p.status=1 ";
    $sql .= "LEFT JOIN ".$this->tables["url_alias"]." ua ON ua.product_id=p.product_id ";
```

Comment: `url_alias` table has no `product_id` column. (Though it should, see Steve's comment under the question.) But as it is, this query won't work.